# How do I set the Spring MVC View Resolver to a servlet?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

In my application I have a servlet in my `web.xml` which processes all the views. This serlvet is a custom template engine like Tiles:

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>TemplateServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>template</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mj.cchp.view.TemplateServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cache_previous_screen_attributes</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cache_previous_screen_parameters</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>template</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.screen</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I want to return to screen name from my controller as `abc.screen` and I want to display the jsp after being processed by the servlet. How should I configure this in my `dispatcher-servlet.xml`?